# Adding KSOAP2 in non-gradle Android Studio project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-ksoap2

I have an existing project that was built without gradle for Android Studio and I'm trying to get KSOAP2 to import.

I've tried adding the ksoap2-android.3.6.2.jar file to /lib/ and then right clicking and picking add to library but then a pop up menu comes up telling me it doesn't recognize the file type and to decide if it's a class, jar director, etc. I tried picking jar directory and then I added to my code

```
import org.ksoap2.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
```

but studio complains that it can't find ksoap2.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: if it is not gradle, what are you using to build your app?

Comment: @njzk2 it builds just fine. all the library were added manually. but now I need to add in ksoap2 so I need to know how to do that manually as well.

Comment: but what are you using to build your app?